# What is the name of the process for creating a new DB from an exported snapshot?

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, amazon-rds, snapshot

I need to set up an automated process that:

1. creates a snapshot of an AWS RDS (MySQL) DB
2. uses that snapshot to create a new RDS instance that will be used as an "analytics playground"

I'm looking for the proper name to call the process described in step 2 above. So I ask: what would the DBA community call the process of using a DB snapshot (export) to create a brand new database? Materializing? Restoring? Backing up? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for [nomenclature](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nomenclature) to name the process, I would call it

- DB Sandbox Provisioning
- DB Self-Service Provisioning
- DB Self-Service

If you need an actual process supplied by Amazon, you could look into

- [AWS Control Tower](https://aws.amazon.com/controltower/)
- [AWS Service Catalog](https://aws.amazon.com/servicecatalog/?aws-service-catalog.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&aws-service-catalog.sort-order=desc)

If you are planning to script this yourself, there is always the AWS CLI.

- [create-db-snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/create-db-snapshot.html)
- [restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot.html)

[Check out the Amazon Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.RestoringFromSnapshot.html) for further info.